# Launch multiple programs with batch file - spaces in file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file for launching multiple pieces of software, they are not located in C drive however, and some of the folders have spaces in the name.

So far I have this..Chrome is the only one working.

```
  @echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\SourceTree
start SourceTree.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\Sublime%%Text%%3
start sublime_text.exe
```

Thanks

Update - SourceTree works, sublime isn't because of the spaces in the name.

Update - I believe the underscore isn't working.

Last Update - Got it to work, if anyone was wondering.

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\SourceTree
start SourceTree.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\"Sublime Text 3"
start sublime.exe
```

Comment: you should enclose the entire path in double-quotes in general...

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, if anyone was wondering.

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\SourceTree
start SourceTree.exe

cd /d D:\WEBDEV\"Sublime Text 3"
start sublime.exe
```